# iOS redirect to Setting Home page

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to redirect to Settings home page. The code that I am writing is:

```
-(void)openDeviceSettings{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```

However, this opens the Settings app. If I open General in Settings and then use this function again, it will redirect to the General Settings.

What I would like to achieve is to either redirect to Settings home page. Could someone please help with this.

Comment: The only settings page you are permitted to open from your app is your own apps page.  Using any other URL will get your app rejected for private API use.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11could you explain what does app getting rejected mean? I was able to use this is simulator and also in a basic test app created.

Comment: If you use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` you are OK, but if you try and use other `prefs:` urls to open other settings screens you will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

You can open settings app programmatically use this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```